# i can't access container in a docker

Tags: docker, centos, portainer

I am running several services on my CentOS 7 Linux server.  Nginx and netdata are being run as root and are working well.

I started Portainer as a Docker container:

```
docker volume create portainer_data
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 --name=portainer \
  --restart=always \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v portainer_data:/data \
  portainer/portainer
```

I can connect to the Portainer port locally with `telnet localhost 9000`.  But, when I try to `telnet ip 9000` from an external client PC on the same network, it doesn't connect.

The Linux server does not have a firewall.  Nginx, netdata, and myapp that are not running in Docker work fine.  In short, all other services can be accessed from a Linux server without a firewall, but Docker's internal container service is inaccessible.

What do I need to change to be able to reach the container?

Comment: check whether your portainer is listening on 0.0.0.0:9000 port by executing command: `netstat -tulnp | grep 9000`

Comment: netstat -tulnp | grep 9000 -->>>> tcp6 0 0 :::9000 :::* LISTEN 14467/docker-proxy

Comment: 0:0:0:0:9000 and :::9000 is differ ...'cuz of this?

Comment: :: means that it is listening on any IPv6 addresses. If you don't see tcp 0.0.0.0:9000 too then it is not listening on IPv4 addresses.

Comment: turn off ipv6 ? when i install centos i didn’t do special setting

Comment: turn off centos ipv6 -> fail / docker run ipv6 option false -> fail

Comment: add this links to  /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
and run  "sysctl -p" to effect those

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable you ipv6

add this links to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

to effect those

```
sysctl -p
```